# Subclassing a decorated class

Tags: python, subclass, decorator, metaclass

How would you subclass a decorated class? Here is some code, I guess I must be missing something pretty simple

```
def decorator_with_args(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(cls):
        def wrapper(*wargs, **wkwargs):
            print("wargs", wargs, wkwargs)
            return cls(*wargs, **wkwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@decorator_with_args()
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("args", args, kwargs)


class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass


myClass = MyClass("arg", kwarg="kwarg")
```

This will raise `TypeError` at compile time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file", line 46, in <module>
    class MySubClass(MyClass):
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary 3.4

Comment: What is your expected behaviour here? Would you like `print("wargs", wargs, wkwargs)` to be called each time a subclass of `MySubClass` is initialized?

Comment: For functions `functools.wraps` is used to assign the actual function to the `__wrapped__` attribute of the decorator, you can do something similar: `wrapper.__wrapped__ = cls` and then use `class MySubClass(getattr(MyClass, '__wrapped__', MyClass)):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decorator is wrong. It should be returning a class instead of a function.

```
def decorator_with_args(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(cls):
        class Wrapper(cls):
            def __init__(self, *wargs, **wkwargs):
                print(wargs, wkwargs)

        return Wrapper

    return decorator
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like the error is raised before the wrapper gets called

Comment: Well, my previous version of the answer was not quite accurate (post edited). You should have no `wrapper` function at all - in your case, the subclass plays the role of the wrapper. `wrapped` was not called, because it was expected to be a class, but it was a function.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bartosz, but your updated version wont do any good, the error will still be raised. The code I provided is a simplified version of a project where `wrapper` exists

Comment: Then I think there is no good way to subclass. It seems that your decorator does not return a class, but a function that pretends to be a class (you get an instance if you call it). But a function returning an instance does not let you create a subclass in a nice way (well, you could do `class MySubClass(type(MyClass()))` but it obviously sucks).

Comment: Ok, so it is as simple as I thought :) I guess `wrapper` should be a class instead of a function. I'll update your answer with a working version and accept it for pointing me in the right direction.